# SpriteKit make two force on a body with joint

Tags: objective-c, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

The problem: I want balloons rise up in the air. They can collide with one another and  they can rotate. With a gravitiy in upright direction that works fine.

But now I want to connect a basket to each balloon. Doing so will result in the basket "flying" up like the balloon. But in real life the basket should be "heavier" than the balloon, so it would always point downwards to earth.

How would I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

One way to simulate a balloon with a basket is to set gravity to be in the downward direction to pull the basket toward the bottom of the scene and apply a buoyant force to the balloon to create lift. Here's an example of how to do that:

Define the constants

```
#define kRandMax        0x7fffffff
#define kNumBalloons    5
```

Create the balloons and baskets

```
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -3);

for (int i=0;i<kNumBalloons;i++) {

    // Create a balloon near the bottom of the scene with a random x position
    SKShapeNode *balloon = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithCircleOfRadius:16];
    balloon.fillColor = [SKColor redColor];
            balloon.name = @"balloon";
    balloon.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
    CGFloat rand1 = arc4random_uniform(kRandMax) / (double)kRandMax;
    // A value in (-view.frame.size.width/2, view.frame.size.width/2)
    CGFloat xOffset = (rand1 - 0.5) *  view.frame.size.width / 2;
    balloon.position = CGPointMake (CGRectGetMidX(view.frame)+xOffset,
                                    CGRectGetMinY(view.frame)+50);
    balloon.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:16];
    [self addChild:balloon];

    // Create the basket        
    SKSpriteNode *basket = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor brownColor] size:CGSizeMake(8, 8)];
    basket.position = CGPointMake(balloon.position.x, balloon.position.y-24);
    basket.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:basket.size.width/2];
    [self addChild:basket];

    // Connect the balloon and basket with an SKPhysicsJointPin
    SKPhysicsJointPin *joint = [SKPhysicsJointPin jointWithBodyA:balloon.physicsBody
                                bodyB:basket.physicsBody anchor:balloon.position];
    [self.physicsWorld addJoint:joint];
}
```

In the update method, apply a force to each balloon to create lift

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    // Apply buoyant force to all balloons in the scene
    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"//balloon" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop){
        // Adjust force as needed
        [node.physicsBody applyForce:CGVectorMake(0, 17.2)];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into `SKPhysicsBody` documentations (can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html)).

Look into `Defining a Body’s Physical Properties` section.
Every physics body has properties (such as mass) that you want to play with, in order to get a more 'realistic' behaviour.

If you want a less general answer,
Post some code examples.

Good luck mate.

Answer (score 0):

I have now a solution like this:

I create a forcefield going up

```
func createForceField(strength:Float) {
    // add force field
    for i in 1...9 {
        let field = SKFieldNode.electricField()
        field.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysikcsCategory.ForceField
        field.position = CGPointMake(frame.size.width*0.1*CGFloat(i), -1000)
        field.strength = strength
        addChild(field)
    }
}
```

Before starting the game I turn on gravity and forcefield

```
override init(size: CGSize) {

    super.init(size: size)

    // Set-Up forcefield
    createForceField(0.1)
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -0.09)

    startGame()

}
```

here I create the balloons with a rope and tag, the balloon is charged so it will react to the forcefield

func createBalloon(vokabel:Vokabel) {

```
    let x = self.frame.width*0.2
    let y = self.frame.height*0.2

    // Balloon
    var balloon = BalloonNode()
    balloon.size =  CGSizeMake(balloon.size.width*0.7, balloon.size.height*0.7)
    balloon.position = CGPointMake(x-6,y)
    balloon.name = "SPRITE"
    balloon.vokabel = vokabel
    balloon.score = 50
    balloonLayer.addChild(balloon)

    // Special Start
    var specialStar = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Star")
    specialStar.size =  CGSizeMake(balloon.size.width*0.7, balloon.size.height*0.7)
    specialStar.hidden = true
    specialStar.name = "STAR"  
    balloon.addChild(specialStar)


    // Rope
    let rope = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.blackColor(), size: CGSize(width: 2, height: 15))
    rope.position = CGPointMake(x, y-balloon.size.height/2-rope.size.height/2)
    rope.alpha = 0.2
    balloonLayer.addChild(rope)

    // Tag
    var labelText = getLabelText(vokabel)
    let tag = createTagWithText(labelText)
    tag.position = CGPointMake(x, y-balloon.size.height/2-rope.size.height)
    balloonLayer.addChild(tag)

    self.physicsWorld.gravity=CGVectorMake(0.0, -0.3)

    // physical bodies

    balloon.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: balloon.size)  
    rope.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: rope.size)
    tag.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: tag.size)

    // physical forces
    balloon.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    balloon.physicsBody?.charge = 0.5
    tag.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    tag.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 1.0
    rope.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 1.0

    // anchor Points
    let anchorBalloonRope = CGPointMake(x, y-balloon.size.height/2)
    let anchorRopeTag = CGPointMake(x, y-balloon.size.height/2-rope.size.height)

    // create joints
    let joint = SKPhysicsJointPin.jointWithBodyA(balloon.physicsBody, bodyB: rope.physicsBody, anchor: anchorBalloonRope)
    let joint_rope_tag = SKPhysicsJointPin.jointWithBodyA(rope.physicsBody, bodyB: tag.physicsBody, anchor: anchorRopeTag)

    // add joints to physic
    self.physicsWorld.addJoint(joint)
    self.physicsWorld.addJoint(joint_rope_tag)

    // give it a horizontal push
    balloon.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(10.0, 0.0))



    // BalloonNode ( is just a layer, has no special position so it is the same coordinate system as the gamelayer)
    let node = BalloonNode()
    node.vokabel = vokabel
    node.score = SCORE_STANDARD
    node.name = "BALLOON"
    node.rope = rope
    node.tag = tag


}
```